# Segmentation fault when calling enif_free()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, erlang

I have some code that should manage a 3 dimensional array with O(1) access and reading time in Erlang. Therefor I'm using Erlang NIFs. Everything is working fine except for the release() function. I always get a segmentation fault when calling it and I have no idea why.

Here is my code:

```
#include "erl_nif.h"

static ErlNifResourceType *DATA_RESOURCE;

typedef struct
{
    int size;
    ERL_NIF_TERM *** array;
    ERL_NIF_TERM defaultValue;
} DATA;

static ERL_NIF_TERM new3DimArray(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
    DATA *data = (DATA *)enif_alloc_resource(DATA_RESOURCE, sizeof(DATA));
    int size;
    enif_get_int(env, argv[0], &size);
    if(argc > 1)
    {
        data->defaultValue = argv[1];
    }else{
        data->defaultValue = NULL;
    }
    data->size = size;
    data->array =  (ERL_NIF_TERM ***)enif_alloc(sizeof(ERL_NIF_TERM **) * size);
    int x = 0;
    while(x < size)
    {
        data->array[x] = (ERL_NIF_TERM **)enif_alloc(sizeof(ERL_NIF_TERM *) * size);
        int y = 0;
        while(y < size)
        {
            data->array[x][y] =  (ERL_NIF_TERM *)enif_alloc(sizeof(ERL_NIF_TERM) * size);
            y++;
        }
        x++;
    }
    return enif_make_resource(env, data);
}

static ERL_NIF_TERM get_nif(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
    DATA *data;
    enif_get_resource(env, argv[0], DATA_RESOURCE, &data);
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    enif_get_int(env, argv[1], &x);
    enif_get_int(env, argv[2], &y);
    enif_get_int(env, argv[3], &z);
    ERL_NIF_TERM res = data->array[x][y][z];
    if(res == NULL && data->defaultValue != NULL)
    {
        res = data->defaultValue;
    }
    return res;
}

static void set_nif(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
    DATA *data;
    enif_get_resource(env, argv[0], DATA_RESOURCE, &data);
    int x;
    int y;
    int z;
    enif_get_int(env, argv[1], &x);
    enif_get_int(env, argv[2], &y);
    enif_get_int(env, argv[3], &z);
    ERL_NIF_TERM value = argv[4];
    data->array[x][y][z] = value;
}

static void release(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
    DATA *data;
    enif_get_resource(env, argv[0], DATA_RESOURCE, &data);
    int x = 0;
    while(x < data->size)
    {
        int y = 0;
        while(y < data->size)
        {
            enif_free(data->array[x][y]);
            y++;
        }
        enif_free(data->array[x]);
        x++;
    }
    enif_free(data->array);
    enif_release_resource(data);
}

static void cleanup(ErlNifEnv *env, void *obj){}

static int load(ErlNifEnv *env, void **priv_data, ERL_NIF_TERM load_info){
    DATA_RESOURCE = enif_open_resource_type(env, "mutArray", "DATA_RESOURCE", &cleanup, ERL_NIF_RT_CREATE, 0);
    return 0;
}

static ErlNifFunc nif_funcs[] = {
    {"new_3_dim_array", 1, new3DimArray},
    {"new_3_dim_array", 2, new3DimArray},
    {"get", 4, get_nif},
    {"set", 5, set_nif},
    {"release", 1, release}
};

ERL_NIF_INIT(mutArray, nif_funcs, load, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

This is my Erlang code (to make the arity clearer):

```
module(mutArray).

%% ====================================================================
%% API functions
%% ====================================================================
-export([init/0, new_3_dim_array/1, new_3_dim_array/2, get/4, set/5, release/1]).

init() ->
    erlang:load_nif("./mutArray", 0).

new_3_dim_array(_Size) ->
    "NIF not loaded yet.".

new_3_dim_array(_Size, _DefaultValue) ->
    "NIF not loaded yet.".

get(_Array, _X, _Y, _Z) ->
    "NIF not loaded yet.".

set(_Array, _X, _Y, _Z, _Value) ->
    "NIF not loaded yet.".

release(_Array) ->
    "NIF not loaded yet.".
```

Btw, this is my Testcode:

```
mutArray:init(),
A = mutArray:new_3_dim_array(100),
mutArray:release(A).
```

EDIT: Ok it gets more and more weird... After some testing I fidured out that I get `** exception error: []` if `enif_free(data->array);` is the last call of the function. At every other position I still get the segmentation fault, even if there is just a println() after `enif_free(data->array);`. After some debugging I also figured out that every line before `enif_free(data->array);` was called. So the exception seems to happen at `enif_free(data->array)`. Does anybody know what this means?

EDIT2: Simply leaving `enif_free(data->array);` out doesn't help either. I get a segmentation fault then as well.

Comment: One problem is that you're assuming the default value of an `ERL_NIF_TERM` can meaningfully be compared to `NULL`. The C compiler is likely warning you about this. You need to fix that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get your code running correctly by fixing several problems.

First, your code assumes that it's OK to check the validity of an `ERL_NIF_TERM` by comparing it to `NULL`, which is incorrect. You can fix this by either initializing all of your array elements to 0 (by calling `enif_make_int(env, 0)` to set each element), or by using an array of structs where each struct holds an `ERL_NIF_TERM` and an `unsigned char` flag to indicate whether the term is valid or not. If you choose the latter approach, you could simply `memset` the struct values to 0, and if a caller requests an uninitialized element via `mutArray:get/4`, just return `enif_make_badarg(env)` to indicate they passed bad arguments to the call.

Second, both your `set_nif` and `release` functions are declared to return `void` when they need to return `ERL_NIF_TERM` instead. To fix this you can correct their return types, and then return `argv[4]` from `set_nif` and `enif_make_int(env, 0)` from `release`.

Lastly, the second argument to your `enif_open_resource_type` call needs to be `NULL` rather than the `"mutArray"` value you're passing, as [the erl_nif man page](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_nif.html#enif_open_resource_type) indicates.